# Sharing a Partition Between Windows and Linux Throws Permission Errors

Tags: linux, windows, cgroups, fat32, vfat

I created a new partition in Windows 10 formatted as Fat32, so that I could work with files located in one place despite being logged into my MX Linux installation or Windows 10.
While logged into Windows 10, I can move files in and out of the partition no problem.
While logged into MX Linux, the drive wasn't mounted, so I modified /etc/fstab by adding this line:

```
UUID=3F02-4BFD /mnt/sda4 vfat defaults 0 2
```

Then I rebooted, only to find I couldn't mkdir inside /mnt/sda4.  So I looked up the permissions and found that every owner and group was root.

So I logged into root and attempted to run:

```
chown foo:users sda4/
```

and got the error:

```
chown: changing ownership of 'sda4/': Operation not permitted
```

Note that I got with this sudo and while actually logged in as the root user.

I did some research and apparently there might be some immutability properties so I ran:

```
lsattr sda4/
```

And got this on all of the directories:

```
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on sda4/foo
```

Currently stuck at this point.

Comment: Read `man mount mount.vfat`. You can specify `uid=` and `gid=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best not to use FAT32 for larger partitions. Use NTFS.
FAT32 has a file size limit of 4GB and you cannot then copy large files to it. It also does not have a journal so chkdsk can take longer or not be able to repair it.

You cannot change permissions nor ownership on Windows formatted partitions. How you mount it is then the default. And root is often normal owner, but permissions opened up to make it usable. But you can make owner user 1000 when mounting.

Are you manually mounting or using fstab.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media

An example of parameters for NTFS.

```
  nodev,permissions,windows_names,nosuid,noatime,async,big_writes,timeout=2,uid=1000,gid=1000 windows_names,big_writes
```

big-writes helps speed, and windows_names prevents use of invalid characters that are valid in Linux. Use noatime if SSD or relatime if HDD.

My ESP - efi system partition is mounted this way, but it is a smaller partition.

```
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

You may also have issues with hibernation. Fast start up uses the hibernation flag and the Linux tools will not normally mount hibernated partitions to prevent damage.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions &

https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation